# How can I use my gamepad trackball with Crysis 2 and Xpadder?

Tags: controllers, crysis-2, xpadder

I've recently installed Crysis 2 in my PC (Win7 x64bit). I wanted to use my joystick (a gamepad like the ones for the PlayStation) with the game.

So I've installed Xpadder to make the joystick available to the game. It works, but the trackball that comes with it won't work.

When I try to use the joystick, the keyword is replaced with the joystick, and that's fine, but I can't replace the mouse movements with the joystick (I can't move his head without the mouse).

I've tried disabling the mouse, but when I do that, there's no head movement at all.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help, but I know the PC version works well with the XBox 360 controller.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this out.. i had the same problem of not being able to control the camera with my gamepad. The problem was fixed when I enabled the 'mode' button on the gamepad. Check to see if you have something like that. I used [this](http://xinput.googlecode.com/files/xbox360cemu.v.3.0.rar) instead of xpadder. Copy the extracted contents from the .rar file into the bin32 folder of your crisis 2 installation and run the little app before launching the game.